# Using .then on a function which returns a promise is throwing "this is not callable"

Tags: typescript, es6-promise

I am importing a module which has a bunch of functions as properties and accessing the functions with strings like this:

```
imported_module[typed enumerated string]().then(res => console.log(res))
```

This throws an error as follows:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Each member of the union type '(<TResult1 = UserResult, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: UserResult) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | null | undefine
d, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<...>) | ... 1 more ... | undefined) => Promise<...>) | (<TResult1 = void, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((
value: void) => TRes...' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.  TS2349
```

How can I fix this? is it a problem with the package?

Comment: Can you tell whether the problem is caused by `imported_module[typed enumerated string]()` or `.then(...)`?  That TypeScript error message is cryptic to me though it sounds like a type mismatch, so I'd probably break the statement up into two pieces and see which piece causes the error.  Do you have type definitions for your imported module?